# Unable to install Grunt in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

```
:~$ npm install -g grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
../src/node_crypto_bio.cc:213: size_t node::NodeBIO::Read(char*, size_t): Assertion `read_head_ != write_head_' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried to install [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) but got this error.
I have node and npm installed already.
Please someone help me resolve this problem!

Comment: version of node & npm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this command.

## npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/